# Sphinx search is not working in my wamp environment?

Tags: php, mysql, search, error-handling, sphinx

Hi I tried to configure sphinx search in my WAMP environment.

THis is my sphinx.conf file

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

source combinedobject
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = root
    sql_db          = digi_inter
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT file_id, file_idas int_attr, object_type_id, searchtext from image_gallery ;

    sql_attr_uint           = int_attr
    sql_attr_uint           = object_type_id
    sql_field_string        = searchtext

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM image_gallery WHERE file_id=$id
}


index combinedobject
{
    source          = combinedobject
    path            = D:\PHP_Projects\DigiInternational\sphinx\data\combinedobject
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type    = sbcs
}



indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    log             = D:\PHP_Projects\DigiInternational\sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log       = D:\PHP_Projects\DigiInternational\sphinx\log\query.log
    pid_file        = D:\PHP_Projects\DigiInternational\sphinx\log\searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    compat_sphinxql_magics  = 1
}
```

I created this kind of a php file inside api folder

```
<?php
$searchName = "food";
require_once('sphinxapi.php');
//Sphinx
$s = new SphinxClient();
$s->setServer("localhost", 8080);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$result = $s->query("@searchtext $searchName");
print_r($result);

?>
```

Through command prompt searchtext is showing result. But with file_id and object_type_id its not showing any result.

Using php nothing is showing. My sphinx version is sphinx-0.9.8-win32. Any body can help me please.

Thanks

Comment: What does print_r($s->showLastError()); show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! So server is listening on port 9312

```
listen          = 9312
```

why then do you try to connect to 8080?

```
$s->setServer("localhost", 8080);
```